# Можно ли менять права каналам на сервере дискорд? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

Столкнулся с проблемой: права для роли muted нужно давать всем каналам на сервере, можно ли сделать так чтобы бот добавлял всем каналам роль muted и забирал у неё права на написание текста?

Вот код, если требуется

````
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
     if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name='Muted')
        await ctx.add_roles(member, role)
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Юзер замьючен!", description="**{0}** Пользователь который замьютил: **{1}**!".format(member, ctx.message.author), color=0xff00f6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
     else:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Нет прав.", description="У тебя нет прав чтобы выполнить эту команду.", color=0xff00f6)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Context

async def create_mute_role(ctx: Context):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id=145124235415)

    for channel in ctx.guild.channels:
        if isinstance(channel, discord.TextChannel):
            await channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False, add_reactions=False)
```

Прочитать про **set_permissions**, можно в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions).